# Convert device log text file to json using python

Tags: python, json, logging

I am working on parsing device logs obtained from [broadcom](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/fibre-channel-networking/fabric-os/fabric-os-commands/9-1-x/Fabric-OS-Commands/fdmiShow.html)

Log text file is like this

```
bmx-95-ccs019:FID928:admin> fdmishow
Local HBA database contains:
  10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e
  Ports: 1
    10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e
      Port attributes:
        FC4 Types: FCP FC-CT FC-NVMe
        Supported Speed: 4 8 16 Gb/s
        Port Speed: 16 Gb/s
        Max Frame Size: 2048 bytes
        Device Name: /sys/class/imse_host/host6
        Host Name: localhost.localdomain
        Node Name: 10:00:00:80:re:e1:3d:6g
        Port Name: 10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e
        Port Type: N_Port (0x1)
        Port Symb Name: 1
        Class of Service: 2, 3
        Fabric Name: 20:51:88:94:71:dd:cb:ec
        FC4 Active Type: FCP FC-CT FC-NVMe
        Port State: 0x2
        Discovered Ports: 0x0
        Port Identifier: 0x015100
  HBA attributes:
    Node Name: 10:00:00:80:re:e1:3d:6g
    Manufacturer: Dzango
    Serial Number: 11S01CV842Y650HY67L0VG
    Model: 01CV842
    Model Description: Dzango 01CV842 16Gb FC Dual-port HBA
    Hardware Version: 0000000c
    Driver Version: 14.0.0.4
    Option ROM Version: 14.0.376.10
    Firmware Version: 14.0.376.10
    OS Name and Version: Linux 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 15 22:12:19 EDT 2022
    Max CT Payload Length: 245760 words
    Symbolic Name: Dzango 01CV842 FV14.0.376.10 DV14.0.0.4 HN:localhost.localdomain OS:Linux
    Number of Ports: 1
    Fabric Name: 10:00:88:94:71:dd:cb:ec
    Bios Version: 14.0.376.8
    Vendor Identifier: Dzango

  87:22:a0:r0:00:30:d1:51
  Ports: 1
    87:22:a0:r0:00:30:d1:51
      Port attributes:
        FC4 Types: FCP
        Supported Speed: 8 16 32 Gb/s
        Port Speed: 32 Gb/s
        Max Frame Size: 2048 bytes
        Device Name: qla2xxx
  HBA attributes:
    Node Name: 57:42:b0:f0:00:10:1c:00
    Manufacturer: Cisno ITL
    Serial Number: D91375
    Model: QLE2764
    Model Description: Cisno 32Gb 4-port Fibre Channel adapter
    Hardware Version: 
    Driver Version: 8.02.01-k4
    Option ROM Version: 0.00
    Firmware Version: 9.08.01 (d0d5)

  35:12:y0:r0:00:90:1z:96
  Ports: 1
    35:12:y0:r0:00:90:1z:96
      Port attributes:
        FC4 Types: FCP
        Supported Speed: 8 16 32 Gb/s
        Port Speed: 32 Gb/s
        Max Frame Size: 2048 bytes
        Device Name: qla2xxx
  HBA attributes:
    Node Name: 57:42:b0:f0:00:10:1c:00
    Manufacturer: Xepang DT
    Serial Number: E000916
    Model: XPE0002764
    Model Description: Xepang 32Gb 4-port Fibre Channel adapter
    Hardware Version: 
    Driver Version: 8.02.01-k4
    Option ROM Version: 0.00
    Firmware Version: 9.08.01 (d0d5)


Local Port database contains:
  10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e
  87:22:a0:r0:00:30:d1:51
  35:12:y0:r0:00:90:1z:96
```

While I will be fetching most of the attributes from each block that starts with "Ports: 1" , below I have given minimum to understand

```
import pandas as pd, re, json, sys
switch_file = sys.argv[1]
switch_name= switch_file.split('.')[0]
with open(switch_file) as f:
     for line in f:
        m_node_name=re.match(r'(^\s+Node\sName):\s(.*)',line)
        if m_node_name:
            node_name_li.append({m_node_name.group(1).strip() : m_node_name.group(2).strip()})
        m_port_name=re.match(r'(^\s+Port\sName):\s(.*)',line)
        if m_port_name:
            port_name_li.append({m_port_name.group(1).strip() : m_port_name.group(2).strip()})
        m_serial_number=re.match(r'(^\s+Serial\sNumber):\s(.*)',line)
        if m_serial_number:
            serial_number_li.append({m_serial_number.group(1).strip() : m_serial_number.group(2).strip()})
        m_model=re.match(r'(^\s+Model):\s(.*)',line)
        if m_model:
            model_li.append({m_model.group(1).strip() : m_model.group(2).strip()})
dic = { "Switch Name": switch_name , "Ports":[ node_name_li , port_name_li, model_li, serial_number_li ]}
print(json.dumps(dic))
```

Output at present

{"Switch Name": "bmx-95-ccs019", "Ports": [[{"Node Name": "10:00:00:80:re:e1:3d:6g"}, {"Node Name": "10:00:00:80:re:e1:3d:6g"}, {"Node Name": "57:42:b0:f0:00:10:1c:00"}, {"Node Name": "57:42:b0:f0:00:10:1c:00"}], [{"Port Name": "10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e"}], [{"Model": "01CV842"}, {"Model": "QLE2764"}, {"Model": "XPE0002764"}], [{"Serial Number": "11S01CV842Y650HY67L0VG"}, {"Serial Number": "D91375"}, {"Serial Number": "E000916"}]]}

Instead please help me achieve meaningful output, which groups all attributes for every "Port" (Ports: 1 block)

Expected output

```
    {
   "Switch Name":"bmx-95-ccs019",
   "Ports":[
      {
         "port":"10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e",
         "Node Name":"10:00:00:80:re:e1:3d:6g",
         "Port Name":"10:00:00:30:ma:i1:3g:2e",
         "Serial Number":"11S01CV842Y650HY67L0VG",
         "Model":"D91375"
      },
      {
         "port":"87:22:a0:r0:00:30:d1:51",
         "Node Name":"57:42:b0:f0:00:10:1c:00",
         "Serial Number":"ZZB890UDS091",
         "Model":"QLE2764"
      },
      {
       ..
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```py
import json
import re
import sys

switch_file = sys.argv[1]
switch_name = switch_file.split(".")[0]

node_name_li, port_name_li, serial_number_li, model_li = [], [], [], []

with open(switch_file) as f:
    port_info = {}
    for line in f:
        m_node_name = re.match(r"(^\s+Node\sName):\s(.*)", line)
        m_port_name = re.match(r"(^\s+Port\sName):\s(.*)", line)
        m_serial_number = re.match(r"(^\s+Serial\sNumber):\s(.*)", line)
        m_model = re.match(r"(^\s+Model):\s(.*)", line)

        if m_node_name:
            port_info[m_node_name.group(1).strip()] = m_node_name.group(2).strip()
        elif m_port_name:
            port_info[m_port_name.group(1).strip()] = m_port_name.group(2).strip()
        elif m_serial_number:
            port_info[m_serial_number.group(1).strip()] = m_serial_number.group(
                2
            ).strip()
        elif m_model:
            port_info[m_model.group(1).strip()] = m_model.group(2).strip()

        if line.strip() == "":
            if port_info:
                node_name_li.append(port_info)
                port_info = {}

if port_info:
    node_name_li.append(port_info)

dic = {"Switch Name": switch_name, "Ports": node_name_li}
print(json.dumps(dic, indent=4))
```